# How would a parallel convoy orchestration behave in an active active server farm

Tags: biztalk

Had an orchestration following the parallel convoy pattern to receive and wait a bunch of messages before kicking off the flow. Question is we are to move to an high variability environment with multiple active-active biztalk servers, would this be a problem? will the messagebox smart enough to figure out which host instance it should push the message to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's no problem at all.  Don't even think about it.

An Orchestration can run an any available Host Computer but a specific instance of an Orchestration would only run on one at a time.

It doesn't matter which one.